# Yield return in local recursive function

Tags: c#

I thought with the new fancy C# local functions I could get rid of the
mandatory private recursion function.
Obviously this function "should" do some post order traverasal of a tree. So, only give the element IFF there is no left or right child available.

The code compiles, it "works", but the recursive calls to the local function:
 `PostOrderRecursive(currentNode.Left);` and `PostOrderRecursive(currentNode.Right);` are ignored when debugging. So no recursion is performed at all.

What is the problem here? Thanks in advance!

```
public IEnumerable<ElementType> GetSubtreeFlattenedPostOrder()
{
    return PostOrderRecursive(this);

    IEnumerable<ElementType> PostOrderRecursive(BinaryTree<ElementType> currentNode)
    {
        if (currentNode.HasLeft)
            PostOrderRecursive(currentNode.Left);
        if (currentNode.HasRight)
            PostOrderRecursive(currentNode.Right);

        yield return currentNode.element;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is either `HasLeft` or `HasRight` ever `true`? If not, debug them and find out why.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nested methods don't behave any differently to regular methods with respect to the effect of `yield return`.

It's not that the methods are ignored - it's that you're not using the value returned from them, which makes them pointless. In fact, you won't even *enter* the body of the method recursively, because that doesn't happen until you call `MoveNext()` on the enumerator returned by the `GetEnumerator()` call to the returned `IEnumerable<>`.

Unfortunately C# doesn't have a sort of "yield foreach" syntax, so you have to iterate over all the values and yield them directly:

```
public IEnumerable<ElementType> GetSubtreeFlattenedPostOrder()
{
    return PostOrderRecursive(this);

    IEnumerable<ElementType> PostOrderRecursive(BinaryTree<ElementType> currentNode)
    {
        if (currentNode.HasLeft)
        {
            foreach (var node in PostOrderRecursive(currentNode.Left))
            {
                yield return node;
            }
        }
        if (currentNode.HasRight)
        {
            foreach (var node in PostOrderRecursive(currentNode.Right))
            {
                yield return node;
            }
        }

        yield return currentNode.element;
    }
}
```

One point to note: this implementation performs poorly, because it needs to create so many iterators. An implementation which avoided recursion but kept a stack or queue of nodes to process could be a lot more efficient. You should bear that in mind if you have any large trees, but it may make sense to keep it simple if performance isn't an issue.

Comment: A perfect time for F#'s `yield!` which solves exactly this problem

Comment: I understood. Thanks! I will accept the answer as soon as i can.

Comment: @Richard: Yes, I'd like to see something like that as well. It's on the C# team's radar, but I don't know whether anything will ever happen: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/378

Comment: @Christoph looks like there is a newer issue for Roslyn: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/25052

Comment: You could `return PostOrderRecursive(currentNode.Left).Concat(PostOrderRecursive(currentNode.Right)).Append(currentNode.element);`

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled upon this from another question. It's very old now, but it looked interesting and I wanted to add another way to do this which more closely resembles the original code:

```
public IEnumerable<ElementType> GetSubtreeFlattenedPostOrder()
{
    return PostOrderRecursive(this);

    IEnumerable<ElementType> PostOrderRecursive(BinaryTree<ElementType> currentNode)
    {
        IEnumerable<ElementType> result = Enumerable.Empty<ElementType>();
        if (currentNode.HasLeft)
            result = result.Concat(PostOrderRecursive(currentNode.Left));
        if (currentNode.HasRight)
            result = result.Concat(PostOrderRecursive(currentNode.Right));

        return result.Append(currentNode.element);
    }
}
```